# How to prevent Show json response to user?

Tags: json, ajax

```js
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     contentType:"application/json;charset=UTF-8",                  
     url:"/api/links/",
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) {
        //some code
     }
)}
```

When a user enter below url in browser:

mydomain/api/links

And press enter key it shows  my json data like :

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "LinkId": 1,
    "Title": "example.com",
    "Url": " www.test.com",
    "IsShow": true,
    "UserId": 1
  },
  {
    "$id": "2",
    "LinkId": 2,
    "Title": "fars.com",
    "Url": "fars.com",
    "IsShow": true,
    "UserId": 1
  }
]
```

Now my question is how to prevent show this data to user?

Comment: It's impossible since what your code can read is what your user can read. However, you can obfuscate the code, encrypt the data to make it difficult to read.

Comment: you cannot, but you use Referer to identify from where the request is coming

Comment: yes.using Referer is the best solution. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is no bulletproof method.

Most of the times whenever an AJAX request is sent to the server, a special header named X-Requested-With with a value of XMLHttpRequest is attached to the request.

So if you want your data to be accessible only through the AJAX request, a simple check to see whether the X-Requested-With header has a value of XMLHttpRequest allows you to decide whether to return JSON with your data or 404.

You can also encrypt your data, as @ymonad has suggested for extra safety, but again, it only makes it harder for user to see, but not even close to impossible.

Comment: Isn't SSL and API Keys a pretty bulletproof method?

Comment: I have assumed that the question was asked in the context of his webpage, not communication between servers through REST API. However you are probably right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 contentType:"application/json;charset=UTF-8",                  
 url:"/api/links/",
 data: JSON.stringify(data),
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (response) {
    location.reload();
 }
 )}
```